# How to add mouse double click to ListBox

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox

To this code: https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/163804-microsoft-working-with-listboxes-part-i/

It is displaying list and looping nicely.

Sadly my guru never finished his code.
So plan would be adding double click detection on a name. How?

```
        case WM_COMMAND:
        {

            return 0;
        }
```

Something like this? 11 is this child window where names are.

```
        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            if (LOWORD(wparam) == 11) {
                if ((message) == LBN_DBLCLK) {
                    cout << "double click" << endl;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lbn-dblclk):

> **Parameters**
>
> **wParam**
>
> The LOWORD contains the identifier of the list box. The HIWORD specifies the notification code.
>
> **lParam**
>
> Handle to the list box.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> This notification code is sent only by a list box that has the `LBS_NOTIFY` style.

So in the first step you need to add this style and use `HIWORD (wParam)` to determine whether to double-click the list.

Then if you need to get the elements of the list, you should not send `LB_GETCURSEL` to `window_handle`, but should send it to `This->listbox_handle`, which is the window handle of the listbox. Then you can get it by sending `LB_GETTEXT` Text content.

Here is the code:

```
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    if (HIWORD(wparam) == LBN_DBLCLK) {
        TCHAR temp[100]{};
        int index = SendMessageW(This->listbox_handle, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0L);
        SendMessageW(This->listbox_handle, LB_GETTEXT, index, (LPARAM)temp);
        MessageBox(window_handle, temp, L"test", 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And it works for me:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
if ((message) == LBN_DBLCLK)
```

with:

```
if (HIWORD (wParam) == LBN_DBLCLK)
```

Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-command).

Comment: Yes, I did get this far also but had to add LBS_NOTIFY to get child window message to come trough.

Comment: OK (that's normally set by the resource editor, but I see you're not using that).  So what problem are you experiencing now?  Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the line after `case WM_COMMAND` and examining `wParam`?

Comment: I am interested to somehow find out what text was clicked. Had a look that Dialog Editor on windows visual studio 2019. I can build there but how do I export it into my code?

Comment: @ayesl `LBN_DBLCLK` doesn’t tell you that info. You will have to handle [`LBN_SELCHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lbn-selchange), or else send [`LB_GETCURSEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lb-getcursel)

Comment: cout << SendMessageW(window_handle, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0L) << endl; But it returns 0 every time i click the list.

Comment: Are you sure you're sending the message to the right window?  You need to send it to the listbox, not the dialog,  Checkout [`GetDlgItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitem), or use the `lParam` value passed in the `WM_COMMAND` message.